# Retrieve custom attribute value in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am using magento 2.1.0, I created custom attribute of customer, and add field on frontend in customer edit information form.

when I entered any value in edit form, it is saved in adimn form but not visible on frontend. means data is not retrieve on frontend.

so how to retrieve that data to show on frontend in this field:

```
     <div class="field bloodgroup">
            <label for="bloodgroup" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('Blood Group') ?></span></label>
            <select name="bloodgroup" id="bloodgroup">
            <?php                   
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                           $model = $objectManager->create('\xxx\xxx\Model\BGroup')->avialable();
            foreach ($model as $b)
            { 
              ?>                    
            <option value="<?php echo $b['BloodGroup']; ?>"><?php echo $b['BloodGroup']; ?></option>

        <?php }   ?>     

            </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please add code which you have tried this far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use below code to retrieve customer attribute value on edit form

```
<?php if($block->getCustomer()->getCustomAttribute('attribute_code')) {
   echo $block->getCustomer()->getCustomAttribute('attribute_code')->getValue();
}?>
```

**EDIT:**

```
    <?php $selected = '';
   if($block->getCustomer()->getCustomAttribute('attribute_code')) {
           $selected = $block->getCustomer()->getCustomAttribute('attribute_code')->getValue();
        }?>
    <div class="field bloodgroup">
                <label for="bloodgroup" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('Blood Group') ?></span></label>
                <select name="bloodgroup" id="bloodgroup">
                <?php                   
                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                               $model = $objectManager->create('\xxx\xxx\Model\BGroup')->avialable();
                foreach ($model as $b)
                { 
                  ?>                    
                <option value="<?php echo $b['BloodGroup']; ?>" <?php 
                 if($selected == $b['BloodGroup']){ ?> selected='selected'      <?php} ?> ><?php echo $b['BloodGroup']; ?></option>

            <?php }   ?>     

                </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, how i used this code in dropdown field?

Comment: Using this code you will get value which is stored

Comment: yes, for text field , i used and get value successfully, but i don't understand how to use this for dropdown, i edit the  the question, please check.

Comment: Updated answer check it

Comment: it is not working, like after save and refresh full form is disable

Comment: not getting please elabrote

Comment: getting full blank screen after using this code

Comment: Updated code check it. developer mode is enable or not?

Comment: change in option "     
    <option value="<?php echo $b['BloodGroup']; ?>" selected="<?php if($selected == $b['BloodGroup']){ echo 'selected'; } ?>">
                    <?php echo $b['BloodGroup']; ?></option>" .  this works for me.  and thank you to help me.